# Javascript Discord bot with command that has multiple words

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I have a piece of code like this.

```
case 'trait':
        if (args[1] === 'aerobic'){
            const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('Aerobic')    
            .addField('Effect','When attacking with Window, gets SPDEF - and SPD +.')
            .addField('Temtem that can have this trait', 'Volarend')
            message.channel.send(embed); 
        }else if (args[1]  === 'air specialist'){
            const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('Air specialist')
            .addField('Effect','+15% damage with Wind techniques.')
            .addField('Temtem that can have this trait', 'Saku, Barnshe, Zebhyruff')
            message.channel.send(embed);
        }else {
            message.channel.sendMessage('Invalid trait (use "-" instaed of space, when using two word trait)')
             }
        break;
```

The first "if" is working as intended but I have problem with the second one because it has two words. I want to use this command on Discord like this

```
!trait air specialist
```

Start of the code looks like this excluding the token, prefix etc.:

```
    bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on('message', message=>{

    const args = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what's the problem in the second `if` when it has two words?

Comment: @Hackinet args is split so each word is a new argument.

Comment: @rivaali Can you tell me, are you ever expecting any more than one argument for the command?

Comment: @rivaali You can use something like this?: else if(args[1]  === 'air' && args[2]  === 'specialist')

Comment: maybe try calling it like `!trait "air specialist"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your message is being split so the two words aren't both in `args[1]`. `args[1]` is "air" and `args[2]` is "specialist".

You could fix this by either changing how you split your message so they are in the same string, or looking at multiple args to enter the else if statement if you still need it split up.

For example your message could be split like this:

```
const args = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ (.*)/);
```

Or you could enter the if statement in a way like this:

```
else if (args[1]  === 'air' && args[2] === 'specialist') { ... }
```

Comment: Your second option there isn't very scalable.  What if he wants to add another trait with 3 words?

Comment: @Tarazed then he'd probably want something more like the first option, obviously the second case is simplistic option for limited edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

One solution if you are only expecting one conditional argument to be included in the command is to re-combine them using concatenation.   This will only work if you are expecting the command and one argument though, if you want 2 or more arguments for a single command, it's a bit more complicated.

```js
case 'trait':
    // We should always have the first one 
    // but you should error check this first.
    let combinedArgs = args[1];

    for(let i = 2; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        combinedArgs += " " + args[i];
    }

    if (combinedArgs === 'aerobic'){

    ... and so on
```